# Start Settings.ACTION_APP_USAGE_SETTINGS for a given UserHandle

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open the digital wellbeing app for a given app and user, but all I can do is open the app for the current user.

I do use the [ACTION_APP_USAGE_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_APP_USAGE_SETTINGS) intent like following:

```
fun startAppUsageStats(context: Context,  userHandle: UserHandle, packageName: String) : Boolean {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        return context.startActivity(
            Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_USAGE_SETTINGS).apply {
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName)
                // does not work...
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_USER, userHandle)
            }.apply {
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            }
        )
    }
    return false
}
```

Any ideas how I can get this working? E.g. I want to open the digital wellbeing app for an app that is only installed inside my working profile and I know the `PackageName` and the `UserHandle` but I don't know how to open the correct version of the digital wellbeing app - the one from the working profile instead of the default one...

Comment: I don't think users are allowed to see each other's data in the settings. Is there something that makes you think it's possible?

Comment: Yes. I can do this sort of thing to launch an app from my normal/work profile, open an apps setting for the normal/work profile and I've seen that some launchers can do what I want to do based on the question here

Comment: So you can open an app's settings for a different user than the current one but you can't open the usage settings in the same way? Have you tried using this method? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/CrossProfileApps#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.UserHandle,%20android.app.Activity)